# Signs of exaltations for all planets

Tags: scripture, astrology

There are nine planets in Hindu astrology. They are Surya, Chandra, Mangal, Budha, Guru, Shukra, Shani, Rahu, Ketu.

What do sign of exaltation for a particular planet signify? And what are signs of exaltation for all nine planets in astrology?

Comment: Surya- Mesha, Shani - Tula, Chandra- Vrisha, Budha- Kanya, Shukra - Meena, Brihaspati- Karka, Mangala- Makara. Ref: BPHS Chapter 3, verse 49

Comment: @Archit Please add it as an answer and possibly what does signs of exaltations signify...

Comment: what do they signify as in? They mean their effects will be highest in those Rashis. I’m still at basics of Jyotisha :D :D

Comment: @Archit I mean the purpose of the sign of exaltation.

Comment: @Archit Haha... Okay...

Comment: No don’t know that hence refraining from writing an answer. Just upvoted the Q

Comment: Every planet represents an aspect of person like Sun is leadership, Moon is emotion, Jupiter is wisdom etc., Their exaltation represents excellence is that particular field for example 1st sign of Aries which represents sheep or majority public masses and a person with exalted Sun in Aries means a leader of public metaphorically shown as sheep. 2nd sign represents family and shown with a bull, so an exalted moon in Taurus represents an emotional person who is protective of family. Similarly exalted Jupiter in 4th Cancer means a person who can make other spiritual like crabs pull each other.